# Renewable primary or unique key

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

There is a table.  No PK, 2 FK, with some arbitrary number of columns.
Unfortunately FK are not unique in any way.

Adding new data is easy.

Deleting data (finding a row) is ok if I put unique constraint to some other col.
(`DELETE ... WHERE fk1=:fk1 AND fk2=:fk2 AND ucol=:ucol`)

What to do with `UPDATE`?

I cant use that ucol because that same ucol might be subject of change. I have several solutions, but none of them seem ok.

**Solution1:**
Put PK in table. Use it for DELETE and UPDATE. Deleting will make lot of holes in it but that's no problem. In theory, it can run out of PK numbers (int, unsigned int) if there's some heavy deleting going on.

**Solution1a**
Make CK of (fk1, fk2, some new col) use that to locate the row. It's the same as just using the PK.

**Solution2**
Use timestamp with microtime/ hash/ unique key generator/ something to populate new unique col. That col is used as PK to locate the row for UPDATE and DELETE. Excellent only if unique algo does it's job perfectly.

My question:
Is there something better? That doesn't require fancy algorithms and have no risk of overflowing auto-incremented PK...

----------------- edit----------------
**Solution2a**
Use mysql [UUID](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_uuid)! It's far better (and easier to use) than, creating custom timestamp / hash / something_unique.

Comment: Hard to answer without more context. How can you run out of 4+ *billions* PK?

Comment: I said 'in theory', didn't I :)  I'll use PK if that's current peak of human knowledge. But if it's not I would love to know better solution.

Comment: If you're that worried about overflowing an integral PK you could always use a GUID, but I'd stick with the standard auto-increment unless you're VERY sure you're going to overflow

Comment: Solution#3: take a course on data modelling and normalisation.

Comment: @ Matt Allwood: Thanks for GUID. It's good stuff :) [link](http://blog.codinghorror.com/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids/) [link2](http://krow.livejournal.com/497839.html)

Comment: @wildplasser: There's no need to be rude. Please provide an meaningful answer if you have one. What normalization could be applied here? What data model could I use in this case?

Comment: I am not being rude. IMHO, this is the kind of problem that disappears once you have formulated it correctly. An example: your `UPDATE ... ucol` observation is actually an example of violating a constraint (involving ucol).

Comment: @CoR Yes you said, but on what numbers do you base your *theory* on? How many inserts are you expecting per minute/hour/day? How many years will it take to reach INT limit? What about BIGINT limit? Also, I still don't understand the context, or what you are trying to achieve exactly, so it's hard to provide a relevant answer.

Comment: @rlanvin: Yes, I'm aware of all that. It's unlikely that limit will ever be reached. I'll end up using PK or UUID. I just wondered if there's a better way to identify a row for UPDATE without artificial PK.

Comment: If your table is intended as a "junction table", then `fk1,fk2` is a *candidate* key. Adding a surrogate key (for use as a PK) is mostly a matter of taste.

Comment: @CoR Yes, a natural key. If you don't have a natural key, then no, use a surrogate key. Also, I think SO isn't the place to discuss theory. If you have a concrete example where you need advice to determine the optimal PK, then please tell. Otherwise, I believe http://dba.stackexchange.com/ or http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ would be more suited to your question.

Comment: @wildplasser: Unfortunately (fk1,fk2) pairs can and will be repeated, so there's no uniqueness. So I need PK or UUID or something else to identify a updating row.

Comment: @rlanvin: Yes, I already had two solutions, so this question was mainly theoretical. But.... using UUID is far better than my original idea with timestamps or hashes. So I did learn something new today :)

Comment: @rlanvin when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: If (fk1,fk2) is *not* a candidate key, there *must* be another column (or set of columns) that you can add to (fk1,fk2) (or use on their own) to function as a unique key ( --> PK) Adding a surrogate does not add meaning.

Comment: @gnat Ok. So, out of curiosity, once this has been pointed out, what is the OP supposed to do? Delete from one site before re-posting to another? Or are you saying referring other sites shouldn't be done?

Comment: @rlanvin did you check [meta guidance](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info) referred in prior comment?

Comment: @wildplasser: Than, that's the answer: No, there's nothing better. There MUST be another unique/pk column. :)

Comment: @gnat I sure did, no posting the same question on multiple sites, I get it (I even [read this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work)). Still don't understand what I should have said though. "I believe you could get more answers there, but cross-posting is frowned upon, so... well too bad, there is nothing you can do"?

Comment: @rlanvin "this can be OK, so long as the question is _tailored_ to each audience on the different sites and is materially different in each case. Just to be 100% clear, copy-pasting a question across sites with no changes is considered abusive behavior"

Comment: @all: no need for copy/pasting. if you feel that "This question doesn't show any research effort; it's unclear or not useful" please give it -1, or close it.  I am glad I was pointed in direction of UUID's and confirmed that there's no way better way that I already had in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my suggestion , it will be better to add a PK to the table because of following reasons:
1. It will give unique id to each row , which will help in DELETE and UPDATE script.
2. PK will create a cluster index on the column which will improve performace of the table while retriving data.
3. Its always adviced to provide a PK in each table.
4. In future you can use the PK as a FK in any table if required.

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I have no problem with PK, I just wanted to know if there's a better way. GUID is third solution so far :)

Comment: It's worth mentioning that PK or UUID are the only solutions.